# QBluetoothSocketPrivate::_q_readNotify() 18 error: -1 "Connection timed out"

Tags: qt, bluetooth, embedded

I am using qt on an embedded board for communication with an IOS device. The embedded board is runnning qt 5.10 and is in peripheral mode. I am getting the above-mentioned error sometimes and after that Bluetooth Error takes place, with error signal as follows

> Error: QLowEnergyController::Error(UnknownError)

How can I know the source of this issue? The document says nothing about it.

The code is based on qt heart rate server example
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtbluetooth-heartrate-server-example.html

My Class for Bluetooth

```
#include "bluetooth.h"

#define log qDebug()<<"["<<__DATE__<<":"<<QTime::currentTime().toString()<<"]"<<"["<<__LINE__<<"]"<<"["<<__FILE__<<"] "

Bluetooth::Bluetooth(mainprocess *main,QObject *parent) :QObject(parent), mainObject(main)
{

   initializeBluetooth();
}

void Bluetooth::initializeBluetooth(){

   try{
       log<<"Initializing Bluetooth...\n";
       //! [Advertising Data]
       advertisingData.setDiscoverability(QLowEnergyAdvertisingData::DiscoverabilityGeneral);
       advertisingData.setLocalName("AtlasGo");
       advertisingData.setServices(QList<QBluetoothUuid>() <<QBluetoothUuid::Atlas);


       // For IOS its readonly and for Atlas its write only
       ReadCharacteristicData.setUuid(QBluetoothUuid::ReadCharacteristic);
       ReadCharacteristicData.setProperties(QLowEnergyCharacteristic::Notify);
       ReadCharacteristicDesc.setUuid(QBluetoothUuid::ClientCharacteristicConfiguration);
       ReadCharacteristicDesc.setValue(QByteArray(2,0));
       ReadCharacteristicData.addDescriptor(ReadCharacteristicDesc);



       // For IOS its write only characteristic and for Atlas its read only
       WriteCharactersiticData.setUuid(QBluetoothUuid::WriteCharacteristic);
       WriteCharactersiticData.setProperties(QLowEnergyCharacteristic::Write |QLowEnergyCharacteristic::Notify);
       WriteCharactersiticDesc.setUuid(QBluetoothUuid::AtlasDescriptor);
       WriteCharactersiticDesc.setValue(QByteArray::fromHex("Write").toHex());
       WriteCharactersiticData.addDescriptor(WriteCharactersiticDesc);

       // For IOS its readonly and for Atlas its write only
       ConnectivityData.setUuid(QBluetoothUuid::Connectivity);
       ConnectivityData.setProperties(QLowEnergyCharacteristic::Notify);
       ConnectivityDesc.setUuid(QBluetoothUuid::ClientCharacteristicConfiguration);
       ConnectivityDesc.setValue(QByteArray(2, 0));
       ConnectivityData.addDescriptor(ConnectivityDesc);


       // For IOS its write only characteristic and for Atlas its read only
       TrackerData_Data.setUuid(QBluetoothUuid::TrackingData);
       TrackerData_Data.setProperties(QLowEnergyCharacteristic::Notify);
       TrackerDesc.setUuid(QBluetoothUuid::ClientCharacteristicConfiguration);
       TrackerDesc.setValue(QByteArray(2, 0));
       TrackerData_Data.addDescriptor(TrackerDesc);



       serviceData.setType(QLowEnergyServiceData::ServiceTypePrimary);
       serviceData.setUuid(QBluetoothUuid::Atlas);


       // Adding characteristic to our service
       serviceData.addCharacteristic(ReadCharacteristicData);
       serviceData.addCharacteristic(WriteCharactersiticData);
       serviceData.addCharacteristic(ConnectivityData);
       serviceData.addCharacteristic(TrackerData_Data);



       leController.reset(QLowEnergyController::createPeripheral()); // We are resetting only the pointer here (leController is a scoped pointer)
       service.reset(leController->addService(serviceData));         // Resetting  only the pointer here (service is a scoped pointer)


       while ( localdevice.hostMode()==QBluetoothLocalDevice::HostPoweredOff){

           log<<"Host is powered off";
           system("sudo rfkill unblock 3");
           system("sudo rfkill unblock 0");
           if(localdevice.hostMode()==QBluetoothLocalDevice::HostConnectable)
               break;


       }



       connect(&heartbeatTimer, &QTimer::timeout,mainObject, &mainprocess::TickProvider);
       connect(leController.data(), &QLowEnergyController::disconnected,mainObject,&mainprocess::reconnect);
       connect(leController.data(), &QLowEnergyController::connected,mainObject,&mainprocess::bleConnected);
       connect(service.data(),&QLowEnergyService::characteristicChanged,mainObject,&mainprocess::parseResponse);
       connect(leController.data(), static_cast<void (QLowEnergyController::*)(QLowEnergyController::Error)>(&QLowEnergyController::error),
               this,&Bluetooth::reconnectOnError);

       leController->startAdvertising(QLowEnergyAdvertisingParameters(), advertisingData,advertisingData);

       // We have to check if advertising succeeded ot not. If there was an advertising error we will
       // try to reinitialize our bluetooth service
       while (leController->state()!= QLowEnergyController::AdvertisingState){
           resetBluetoothService();
           leController->startAdvertising(QLowEnergyAdvertisingParameters(), advertisingData,advertisingData);

       }

       // Timer for periodically sending information to IOS
       // Tracking data
       // Connectivity information
       log<<"Starting the Tick Timer Timer";
       heartbeatTimer.start(66);
       //    heartbeatTimer.start(200); Just for testing
   }
   catch(std::exception e)
   {
       log<<"---------------------";
       log<<"Bluetooth Crashed";
       log<<"---------------------";
       log<<"Bluetooth Initialization failed";
       log<<e.what();
       emit recoverBluetooth();
   }


}

void Bluetooth::reconnectOnDisconnect(){


   try{

       log<<"Bluetooth Device Disconnected";
       log<<"Resetting Bluetooth bt.service";


        //resetBluetoothService();
       if(leController->state()!= QLowEnergyController::ConnectedState){
           //leController->disconnectFromDevice();
           leController.reset(QLowEnergyController::createPeripheral());
           service.reset(leController->addService(serviceData));
       }

       if (!service.isNull()){

           if(leController->state()!=QLowEnergyController::AdvertisingState && leController->state()!=QLowEnergyController::ConnectedState){
               leController->startAdvertising(QLowEnergyAdvertisingParameters(),advertisingData,advertisingData);   //, advertisingData);
           }

           // We have to check if advertising succeeded ot not. If there was an advertising error we will
           // try to reinitialize our bluetooth service
           while (leController->state()!= QLowEnergyController::AdvertisingState && leController->state()!= QLowEnergyController::ConnectedState ){
               resetBluetoothService();
               leController->startAdvertising(QLowEnergyAdvertisingParameters(), advertisingData,advertisingData);

           }

           connect(service.data(),&QLowEnergyService::characteristicChanged,mainObject,&mainprocess::parseResponse);
           connect(leController.data(), &QLowEnergyController::disconnected,mainObject,&mainprocess::reconnect);
           connect(leController.data(), &QLowEnergyController::disconnected,mainObject,&mainprocess::stopTracker);
           connect(leController.data(), &QLowEnergyController::connected,mainObject,&mainprocess::bleConnected);
           connect(leController.data(), static_cast<void (QLowEnergyController::*)(QLowEnergyController::Error)>(&QLowEnergyController::error),
                   this,&Bluetooth::reconnectOnError);


       }
   }
   catch(std::exception e){

       log<<"---------------------";
       log<<"Bluetooth Crashed";
       log<<"---------------------";
       log<<"Error while handling bluetooth Disconnect";
       log<<e.what();
       emit recoverBluetooth();
   }


}

void Bluetooth::reconnectOnError(QLowEnergyController::Error error){


   try{

       // Have to check this error because of Qt's bug. It throws error when remote device disconnects
       if(error!=QLowEnergyController::RemoteHostClosedError){

           log<<"Bluetooth Error !!";
           log<<"Resetting Bluetooth bt.service";
           log<<"Error: "<<error;

          // resetBluetoothService();

           if(leController->state()!= QLowEnergyController::ConnectedState){
               //leController->disconnectFromDevice();
               leController.reset(QLowEnergyController::createPeripheral());
               service.reset(leController->addService(serviceData));
           }


           if (service!=nullptr){

               if(leController->state()!=QLowEnergyController::AdvertisingState && leController->state()!=QLowEnergyController::ConnectedState){
                   leController->startAdvertising(QLowEnergyAdvertisingParameters(),advertisingData,advertisingData);   //, advertisingData);
               }

               // We have to check if advertising succeeded or not. If there was an advertising error we will
               // try to reinitialize our bluetooth service
               while (leController->state()!= QLowEnergyController::AdvertisingState && leController->state()!= QLowEnergyController::ConnectedState ){
                   //resetBluetoothService();
                   leController->startAdvertising(QLowEnergyAdvertisingParameters(), advertisingData,advertisingData);

               }

               // Connections
               connect(service.data(),&QLowEnergyService::characteristicChanged,mainObject,&mainprocess::parseResponse);
               connect(service.data(), QOverload<QLowEnergyService::ServiceError>::of(&QLowEnergyService::error),[=](QLowEnergyService::ServiceError newError){
                   log<<"---------------------";
                   log<<"Bluetooth Service Error:"<<newError;
                   log<<"---------------------";
               });
               connect(leController.data(), &QLowEnergyController::disconnected,mainObject,&mainprocess::reconnect);
               connect(leController.data(), &QLowEnergyController::connected,mainObject,&mainprocess::bleConnected);
               connect(leController.data(), &QLowEnergyController::disconnected,mainObject,&mainprocess::stopTracker);
               connect(leController.data(), static_cast<void (QLowEnergyController::*)(QLowEnergyController::Error)>(&QLowEnergyController::error),
                       this,&Bluetooth::reconnectOnError);


           }
       }
   }

   catch(std::exception e){

       log<<"---------------------";
       log<<"Bluetooth Crashed";
       log<<"---------------------";
       log<<"Error while reconnecting after remote device disconnection";
       log<<e.what();
       emit recoverBluetooth();
   }


}



void Bluetooth::resetBluetoothService(){

   try{

       log<<"Trying to reset bluetooth";
       if(leController->state()==QLowEnergyController::AdvertisingState)
           leController->stopAdvertising();


       // Todo: Use timer
       system("sudo service bluetooth stop");
       QThread::sleep(1);
       system("sudo service bluetooth start");
       QThread::sleep(1);

       log<<"Bluetooth Reset complete";
   }

   catch(std::exception e){
       log<<"---------------------";
       log<<"Bluetooth Crashed";
       log<<"---------------------";
       log<<"Error while resetting bluetooth";
       log<<e.what();
       emit recoverBluetooth();
   }
}
```

Comment: Cant help without seeing any code. Unknown Error usually means your code does something wrong. On either end of the communication. Or your BLE characteristics are misconfigured. Too many possibilities to just guess.

Comment: @markus-nm Thanks for your comment. I have updated my question with the code I am using. Please provide some insight if possible